# Javascript: stopPropagation only works the first time?

Tags: javascript, event-propagation

My button is only being 'clicked' the first time it is clicked. Every time after, the click event is immediately propagated to the parent's onclick. Here is the button's onclick:

```
$('.clickable .moveUp').click(function(e) {
        moveUpWorkoutExercise($(this));
        e.stopPropagation();
    });
```

And the HTML outline:

```
<div class="clickable" onclick="toggleExerciseDetails(311,false)">
    <a class="moveUp disabled" title="Move this exercise up"></a>
```

How can I make the event work every time and not just the first time? Thanks!

Comment: You want to make it so the propagation starts again?

Comment: There is no button, there is a div element containing an A element with no content, it is impossible to click on it. The listener is attached to the div and the A, likely you are only seeing the listener on the div respond. What does *toggleExerciseDetails* do?

Comment: @RobG - the listener is only attached to the anchor element (`$('.clickable .moveUp')` means elements with class "moveUp" that are descendents of class "clickable", right? Not any element of either class.), though the div has its own separate onclick handler set inline. Good catch on not being able to click on an empty anchor, though this might just be an oversimplified example.

Comment: @nnnnnnnnnn — selectors aren't my forte. :-) The OP probably has something different in the page, but impossible to say more without seeing more. If `e.stopPropagation()` works the first time it should work thereafter unless *moveUpWorkoutExercise* is doing something that hasn't been revealed, like moving the A element somewhere else, or removing the listener, or...?

Comment: @RobG  ...or just crashing, like I suggested (guessed) in my answer.

Comment: a row is cloned then removed in the function moveUpWorkoutExercise, so now i assume the event handler is not cloned properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an error occurs within the `moveUpWorkoutExercise()` function then execution of your event handler will stop before it gets to the `e.stopPropagation();` line. Is there something in that function that might break for second and subsequent clicks?

(You could try putting `e.stopPropogation()` first and see what happens, but hypothetically if that does "work" it hasn't really fixed the underlying problem.)